# Does the étale topos determine the Hodge numbers?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, galois-theory, etale-cohomology

Does the small étale topos of a smooth proper variety over a perfect field of positive characteristic determine its Hodge numbers? We consider it as a Grothendieck topos over the étale topos of the field.

Comment: Variety over $\mathbb C$? Over $\mathbb Q$ (or even $\mathbb Q_p$) it certainly does...

Comment: OK. Over some fields (like any number field or $p$-adic field) one can check that the Galois action on the etale cohomology determines the Hodge numbers using $p$-adic Hodge theory. Since this is determined by the etale topos (considered as a topos over the topos of that field), this gives a positive answer in that case. (Maybe you can even reconstruct this Galois group from the abstract topos.)

Comment: @WillSawin but can you single out the relevant sheaf in the topos? I don't know how to define $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as an etale sheaf purely in terms of the topos.

Comment: Well, one wants to construct $\mathbb Z/p^n$ for all $n$. Isn't this the colimit of $p^n$ copies of the final object?

Comment: I think this is false in positive characteristic, because of (inseparably) unirational varieties with interesting Hodge numbers (e.g. supersingular K3 surfaces or Fermat surfaces). From these, you should be able to construct a radicial map of smooth projective surfaces where one is rational and the other has nonzero $h^{0,2}$. But topological invariance of the étale site gives an equivalence between the étale topoi.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Good idea! Specifically, Shioda proved that over the surface with equation $x_1^{q+1} -x_2^{q+1} = x_3^{q+1}- x_4^{q+1}$, the cover defined by adjoining a $q$th root of $(x_1 + x_2)/(x_3-x_4)$ is rational. So one could either try to concretely calculate the singular locus of this cover or show abstractly that it can be smoothed regardless of its singular locus.

Comment: It seems to me that the singularities are at worst on the line $x_1+x_2=x_3-x_4=0$ as everywhere else the derivative of whichever of $(x_1+x_2)/(x_3-x_4)$ or $\frac{(x_3-x_4)/(x_1+x_2)$ is defined is nonvanishing. The rational function is defined on the whole line but I don't know if its derivative vanishes there.

Comment: In Ekedahl's paper "Canonical models of surfaces  of general type" he constructs smooth surfaces of general type over a field of charactersistic $2$ which have a radicial map to $\mathbb{P}^2$ (Proposition 2.14). Some of these surfaces have nonzero $h^{0,1}$

Comment: Here is another possible construction. Consider a smooth non isotrivial fibration of curves $C\to B$ in positive characteristic, where $B$ is a curve (eg a Kodaira-Parshin fibration). Now let $k>0$ and consider the twisted fibration $C^{p^{(k)}}\to B$ (ie the base change of $C$ by the $k$-th power of the absolute Frobenius on $B$). Then the Hodge numbers of $C^{p^{(k)}}$ (viewed as a surface) can be computed and presumably they will differ from those of $C$. On the other hand $C$ and $C^{p^{(k)}}$ are related by the relative Frobenius morphism, which is radicial.

Comment: @WillSawin wait how does your thing with final objects work for non-isomorphic finite abelian groups of equal cardinality? Do they all have isomorphic cohomology groups?

Comment: You have to construct the addition map separately.

Comment: @crispr adding on Will's explanation, the constant sheaf with any value is an invariant of the topos: it is the pullback along the (unique!) terminal geometric morphism to Set of the "sheaf" $A\mapsto(Z/p^n)^A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. See Proposition 2.14 in *[Canonical models of surfaces of general type in positive characteristic](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1988__67__97_0/)*